# iMovie cannot load Sony-MPEG videos

Tags: macos, quicktime, imovie

I recently moved from Windows to OS X, so maybe I'm asking a frequently-asked question. But I did some googling and didn't find a solution yet.

I have a lot of videos on my drive from my SONY camera. The format is MPEG-2 Sony, which is not a standard MPEG-2 format.

How can I use these videos and import them on iMovie? Could QuickTime MPEG-2 Playback Component for Mac OS X help me? Or what else could I do?

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

#### Playing MPEG-2 videos in Quicktime

**[Perian](http://perian.org/#detail)** massively extends the amount of  formats Quicktime can play. It's free.

#### Importing MPEG-2 in iMovie

I'm not aware of any solution to that. But **[Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/)** can help you convert that video to a format that works with iMovie (.avi).

Answer (score 1):

if perian doesn't work, you can convert the files with mpeg streamclip and convert the files to quicktime dv or other flavors.
just google mpeg streamclip, it`s free

Answer (score 0):

Usually, iMovie does allow the import of MPEG files. However, if MPEG (MPG) files are muxed (multiplexed) MPEG-1 or MPEG-2 video, iMovie will refuse to import the MPEG (MPG) files. Then you need to use some converter software to convert MPEG to iMovie compatible format for use in your iMovie project.

This article, **which recommends my product,** will show you how to convert MPEG to iMovie compatible format so as to successfully import MPEG into iMovie, import MPG to iMovie.

[How to Import MPEG to iMovie](http://www.bigasoft.com/articles/how-to-import-mpeg-to-imovie.html)

Comment: yeah, the method from goodbabywell did solve my problem, a fly in the ointment is the software in your article is shareware with only 5 min free tril. anyway, it is really a good app which also helps me to import my other videos like avi, avchd and etc